# How to imitate child selector with Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Fellas!

I have one nasty page to parse but can't figure out how to extract correct data blocks from it using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), because it has no CSS child selector support.

HTML:

```
<ul class="ul-block">
   <li>xxx</li>
   <li>xxx</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>xxx2</li>
      </ul>
</ul>
```

How would I extract (direct) child `li` elements of parent `ul.ul-block`?

The `$node->find('ul[class=ul-block] > li');` doesn't work and `$node->find('ul[class=ul-block] li');` ofc finds also nested descandant `li` elements :(

Comment: Do you depend on using *Simple HTML DOM*? If not have a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/book.simplexml.php) or [php DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/book.dom.php). With both you can use xpath queries, with which it's no problem to select only child elements.

Comment: @Yoshi hey, i'm not quite depend, i have used it for other website scrapping, but i don't see why i couldn't add other parser. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example with [php DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/book.dom.php):

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtml('
<ul class="ul-block">
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>c</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
');

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//ul[@class="ul-block"]/li') as $liNode) {
    echo $liNode->nodeValue, '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and used the children method to grab just the first level items.

```
<ul class="my-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Some Text</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Some Text</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Inner Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the Simple HTML Dom code to get just the first level li items:

```
$html = file_get_html( $url );
$first_level_items = $html->find( '.my-list', 0)->children();

foreach ( $first_level_items as $item ) {
    ... do stuff ...
}
```