# Simple DOM and <li>

Tags: php, dom

I've tried this a few different ways and nothing seems to work.  (I tried all examples at [How to imitate child selector with Simple HTML DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831597/how-to-imitate-child-selector-with-simple-html-dom))  Used code as is, changing what I needed for my needs, ie class=xxx and the url.

So I'm trying pull out some information from a web page.  There are no children to work with as far as DOM is concerned and using the xpath method got me nothing returned. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

```
<div id="wpp-6" class="widget popular-posts">
    <div class="widget_title">POPULAR</div><!-- Wordpress Popular Posts Plugin v2.3.2         [Widget] [daily] [regular] -->
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://link.html" title="Title of post" class="wpp-post-title">THE DATA I    WANT</a> <span class="post-stats"></span>
        </li>
        <!-- More lists -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are about 9 more list statements after that. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell what do you want fetch from this, also can you give the remote page link ?

Comment: Sure.  Remote page is www.psfk.com and all I want are the "Popular" headlines on the right hand side. Don't need the links, just the headline. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useing [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) you can do it easily, Just download the `simple_html_dom.php` file [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) and use it as follows.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html=file_get_html('http://psfk.com');
foreach($html->find('div#wpp-6 ul li a') as $a){
    echo $a->innertext.'<br />';
}
```

### Output will be (Tested on Monday January 14, 2013)

> Google Flu Map Depicts Worst Outbreaks In The USA
>
> Scotch-Tape Portraits Contort Human Faces [Pics]
>
> New Design For Orwell’s Nineteen Eighty-Four Highlights Theme Of
>   Censorship
>
> Vodka Made From Filtering The Liquor Over Nude Models [Video]
>
> Samsung Debuts Flexible Screens
>
> McDonald’s Changes Its Name In Australia
>
> Samsungâ€™s Transparent Screen Is The Retail Window Of The Future
>   [CES]
>
> Dita Von Teese Sews QR Codes Directly Into Her Clothing
>
> Abercrombie & Fitch Boss Makes Flight Attendants Wear Only Boxers
>   & Sandals On Private Jet
>
> Mirror App Shows Women How They Will Age If They Keep Drinking

If you want to print the title with `link` like `<a>...</a>` then just use `echo $a`

Comment: Sheikh,  Thank you.  I was fighting with that for awhile.  Appreciate the help!.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used xpath so here is my solution
You can traverse DOM tree this way, checking for id and class of needed element

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0); //needed because of invalid xml




    $url = "http://www.psfk.com";

    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8'); 
    $str = file_get_contents($url);


    // Load the url's contents into the DOM 
    $xml->loadHTML($str); 



    //Loop through all divs in the dom until we find what we need 
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div) {
        if($div->getAttribute('id') == 'wpp-6' && $div->getAttribute('class') == 'widget popular-posts') {
            if($div->parentNode->getAttribute('id') == 'right') {
                foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
                    foreach($li->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
                        echo $link->textContent . "<br>";;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

?>
```