# DOMDocument get nodeValue of each matching element

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I've been hacking at this for a while and just cant seem to get it right.

How can you get get the contents of all script elements, when the number of script elements is variable. My example markup looks like this:

```
<div></div>
<iframe><iframe>
<script>xxxx</script>
<script>xxxx</script>
<script>xxxx</script>
```

What I have so far works only if I keep the number of scripts static so clearly Im not iterating over the array correctly, but Im totally thrown by the [DOMXPath documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) as how to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
@$dom->loadHtml($form_content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//script');
foreach ($items as $item) {
     $scriptContents = $item->previousSibling->previousSibling->nodeValue . "\r\    n\r\n";
     $scriptContents .= $item->previousSibling->nodeValue . "\r\n\r\n";
     $scriptContents .= $item->nodeValue . "\r\n\r\n";
}
echo $scriptContents;
```

How should I go about this? I've been search SO for a while now, but can seem to apply a solution that works. Thanks in advance - b

Comment: I am not understanding the problem.  If you have 3 `script` tags your foreach will loop 3 times, if you have 10 `script` tags it will iterate 10 times.  What behavior are you seeing that differs from this?  can you show the HTML that would cause this not to be true? Now it is not really clear to me what you are trying to do with `$scriptContents` as you are overwriting the variable with each iteration.  Perhaps this explains the difference in what you expect to happen and what actually happens. To me it looks like this will echo out only the last three sibling nodes of the last script tag.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308778/simple-dom-and-li/14309058#14309058) and the reference of the used library, it's super simple and would let you load `HTML` from a `string` too.

Comment: @MikeBrant - New day and I see it, basic mistake that I overlooked as I thought I was doing something wrong with DOMXPath. As you point out `$scriptContents` was the problem, I need to declare it first, and then `$scriptContents .= $item->previousSibling->nodeValue;` will get the contents of all script nodes as expected. If you want write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are overwriting `$scriptContents` with each iteration, which is probably not what you are intending.  The way the script currently is operating, your output would be limited to the two previous siblings of the last script tag (whether or not they are actually script tags themselves) along with the last script tag.

If you are strictly trying to output the script tags you can do this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//script');
foreach ($items as $item) {
     echo $item->nodeValue . "\r\n\r\n";
}
```