# Using Simple DOM Parser to extract Wordpress post to html

Tags: php, wordpress, simple-html-dom

For parsing the strings inside my Wordpress posts to HTML. I use Simple DOM Parser. With the below code I receive Fatal error: `Call to a member function find() on a non-object`. Could somebody be of helping hand?

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
    require ('simple_html_dom.php');

    /*
    Template Name: Practice
    */


    $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=arthouse' ); 
            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        $query->the_post();

                        $page = the_content().' ';
                        $html = str_get_html($page). " ";

                            foreach($html->find('div[class=post]') as $element) {
                                echo $element->src . '<br>';
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    echo 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.';
                }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I didn't understand, why you are using `DOM parser` here and if you are willing to get all the links from inside the `div[class=post]` using `simple dom parser` then you should write something like this

```
foreach($html->find('div.post a') as $a){ // or div[class=post] a
    echo $a->href.'<br />'; // for link, i.e. http://somedomain.com/somepage.php
    // or
    echo $a; // to print out the link as it's
}
```

This may not right for your layout of html but it may give you an idea, also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308778/simple-dom-and-li/14309058#14309058). If you try this code (fetch all the post title/link from my site), you may get an idea (scrapping my site is not allowed)

```
$html = file_get_html('http://heera.it');
foreach($html->find('section.post-body h3 a') as $a){
    echo $a.'<br />';
}
```

This (`section.post-body h3 a`) to get all the links from inside `h3` tags which is inside `section` tag with class `post-body`.
Again, make sure, why you are using a `Dom parser` ? I think, you don't need to use a parser, maybe you are doing it wrong, I think so.

Comment: I fixed it, had to check 
     if (method_exists($html,"find")) {
          if ($html->find('html')) {