# PHP Simple DOM Parser first child

Tags: php, parsing

this is a sample code:

```
<div class="content">
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text 2</p>
<p>text 3</p>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="205">
                <p>td1</p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="205">
                <p>td2</p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="205">
                <p>td3</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want print just first level p paragraph

So I try this code:

```
foreach($html->find('div.content p') as $p)
{
    echo $p->plaintext;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

I expect these result:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

But I get these:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
td1
td2
td3
```

Is there any way to ignore other p tags?

Comment: I don't know in how far PHP Simple DOM Parser follows css, but I would try `$html->find('div.content > p')` to get the direct children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selectors are the same as in CSS, the selector you are looking for is

```
foreach($html->find('div.content > p') as $p) {
    //                          ^^
    ...
}
```

Using this selectors you find **direct children**, yours `.content p` find all `p` in `.content`, not just direct children.

Comment: It is not work. mybe you are true...becuase p is in table>tbody>tr>td>P  so it's first P!

Comment: You don't want to get the first P child (`p:first-child` which returns `text 1` and `td 1`), but direct children of `div.content` which are exactly the three paragraphs with `text 1-3`. It should work. The selector you write in the comment above if okay, but do you need that? Not sure, paragraphs in TDs are irrelevant, aren't they?

Comment: Yes I don't want paragraphs in TDs, But I testet this code and the result is same as code in my question...

Comment: Hm, PHP Simple DOM don't know child selector, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831597/how-to-imitate-child-selector-with-simple-html-dom, maybe the second answer with `-children` helps you. The accepted one uses `PHP DOM` instead of `Simple DOM`.